# How do the open sets in $X/R$ look like?

Tags: general-topology

Considere $X=\mathbb R$ endowed with its usual topology and define the equivalence relation $R$ in $X$ as follows:

$$xRy\Leftrightarrow (x=y\vee x, y\in [0, 1]).$$

Endow $X/R$ with the quotient topology. Can I write down explicitly the open sets of $X/R$? Is there a way to visualize them?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: Yep, I described the non trivial identifications only.

Comment: This is just collapsing $[0,1]$ to a point $p$, so you have $(\leftarrow,0)\cup\{p\}\cup(0,\to)$, where the first and last pieces pretty clearly have their usual topology. Which sets containing $p$ have open inverse images under the quotient map?

Comment: I think you meant $(1, \to)$ there instead of $(0,\to)$.

Comment: @MJD: I did indeed; thanks!